non-isomorphic number fields
Show that following 2 polynomial do not generate isomorphic number number fields:
$P_1(x)= x^3+10x+1$
$P_2(x) = x^3-8x+15$
I see $Disc(P_1)=Disc(P_2)=-4027$ and both of them have a real root and 2 complex root. I think I must to calculate $\frac{Q[X]}{P_i[X]}$ galois group, but I can't do that...

See here. It follows from Problem $14$, section $7$ that the number fields are non-isomorphic.

Here are the LMFDB pages for the first and second number field. The two properties I notice that are different between the two fields are the Frobenius cycle type at 17 as noted above (and also at 29, 41, and 43); and the regulator.

From the comments:

The first polynomial is irreducible mod $17$, while the second splits into linear factors. Since $17$ is prime to the discriminant, it follows that $17$ remains prime in the ring of integers in the first field but not in the second. – user297024


Here are the LMFDB pages for the first and second number field. The two properties I notice that are different between the two fields are the Frobenius cycle type at $17$ as noted above (and also at $29$, $41$, and $43$); and the regulator. – Viktor Vaughn

